# Clojure multimethod dispatching on functions and values

Tags: clojure

I have a function that returns the indexes in seq s at which value v exists:

```
(defn indexes-of [v s]
  (map first (filter #(= v (last %)) (zipmap (range) s))))
```

What I'd like to do is extend this to apply any arbitrary function for the existence test. My idea is to use a multimethod, but I'm not sure exactly how to detect a function. I want to do this:

```
(defmulti indexes-of ???)
(defmethod indexes-of ??? [v s]  ;; v is a function
  (map first (filter v (zipmap (range) s))))
(defmethod indexes-of ??? [v s]  ;; v is not a function
  (indexes-of #(= v %) s))
```

Is a multimethod the way to go here? If so, how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a multimethod it should be on the filter function, which is the one changing according to the `existence test` type.

So

```
(defmulti filter-test (fn [value element] 
                        (cond 
                         (fn? value) :function
                         :else :value)))

(defmethod filter-test :function
  [value element]
   (apply value [element]))

(defmethod filter-test :value
   [value element]
  (= value element))

(defn indexes-of [v s]
   (map first (filter #(filter-test v (last %)) (zipmap (range) s))))
```

Consider the JVM doesn't support first-class functions, or lambdas, out of the box, so there's no "function" data type to dispatch on, that's the reason the `fn?` test.

None the less the `predicate` solution proposed by `noisesmith` is the proper way to go in this situation IMO.

Comment: It's not my solution, I'm just explaining how to use a multimethod for polymorphic dispatching on the particular question posed. I would do a map-indexed for infinite laz-seqs but its beyond the question IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm accepting it because you answered what I was asking, though as you and others have pointed out, the predicate solution is the best fit for my specific case.

Comment: I wonder if you have even looked at my answer and whether you have noticed that it provides similar functionality but also for infinite lazy-seqs at no additional cost with code-reuse and idiomatic application of keep-indexed?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defmulti indexes-of (fn [v _]
                       (if (fn? v)
                         :function
                         :value)))
(defmethod indexes-of :function
  [f coll]
  (keep-indexed (fn [i v] (when (f v) i)) coll))

(defmethod indexes-of :value
  [v coll]
  (indexes-of (partial = v) coll))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something simpler and more general:

```
(defn index-matches [predicate s]
  (map first (filter (comp predicate second) (map vector (range) s))))

user> (index-matches even? (reverse (range 10)))
(1 3 5 7 9)
user> (index-matches #{3} [0 1 2 3 1 3 44 3 1 3])
(3 5 7 9)
```

thanks to a suggestion from lgrapenthin, this function is also now effective for lazy input:

```
user> (take 1 (index-matches #{300000} (range)))
(300000)
```

Comment: good point, thank you, I was trying to keep close to the original but I have adjusted for that and this function now works for lazy input

Comment: I really like this solution, and in fact chose to go this way. The multimethod would have saved my users three characters whilst costing me many more. :)

Comment: Not only that, but it composes more readily with other clojure idioms than a multimethod would. The "magic" behavior of treating things that are not functions as literal values to match breaks conventions like passing :key-to-check as a predicate for a hashmap or struct.